# Minecraft chunk problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a new PC and I tried to play hardcore world. But something happened, the chunks don't load up really correctly and are repeated everywhere:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried for F3 + A but it doesn't solve this problem... So, my question is... how can I fix this? (I am sure that there is no problem with my graphic card)

EDIT: I am playing on 1.9.2 version

Comment: was it the same after restarting minecraft / your computer? was it singleplayer / multiplayer? did it happen in other worlds?

Comment: I have tried restarting it but it doesn't help. And it happens for everyworld, except superflat world

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling minecraft

Comment: Why are you sure there is no gfx card problem? I had a few driver issues with mc already. I think you really should add more technical info regarding your pc to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue, try lowering your render distance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might be your world seed. Are those actuall pieces of land or just ghost blocks? When you reload the chuncks, do the things dissapear? If no, then you need to make a new world. Sorry.

Comment: have a look in the comments :)

Comment: It is not the world seed. And yes, they are ghost blocks where I can't touch them. I tried reloading the chunck but it doesn't help. The ghost block(misloaded chuncks) follow me everywhere  and annoys me :/ .

Answer (score -3):

Just exit Minecraft and open it again.

Comment: I tried but same thing happen...

Comment: Hm.,,, maybe restart your computer once then if It happens again COMPLETELY exit out of minecraft.. idk it works for me